# MySql update statement not finding any records?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-update

I have an email address field that has many rows(not all of them) with a space after the value, and I'm trying to remove the space.

Can someone fill me in why the select statement would find 900 rows and the update would not find any?  It's the same WHERE clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM `postmeta`
WHERE meta_key = 'email'
AND RIGHT(meta_value,1) = ' ';
-- 900 rows are returned
```

```
UPDATE `postmeta`
SET meta_value = TRIM(meta_value)
WHERE meta_key = 'email'
AND RIGHT(meta_value,1) = ' ';
-- 0 rows are updated
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds stupid-crazy, but you are right.  I might try where LENGTH( meta_value ) > LENGTH( TRIM( meta_value))  -- instead of right, 1..

Comment: I just tested on MySQL 8.0.29 and it worked for me. I inserted one row with email `"bill@example.com "`. Both the SELECT and the UPDATE you show matched the row and changed it. After the UPDATE, the SELECT finds no row.

Comment: How many rows does the update *find*?  The command line client will tell you that, in addition to how many were actually updated.   What data type is meta_value?

Comment: A few extra details:

mySql is version 10.5.17
the column type is LONGTEXT

matched rows from UPDATE statement is 0
matched rows from SELECT is 900

Comment: @DRapp - I tried your suggestion but still no luck.  It finds 0 rows.

Comment: mySql is version 10.5.17  - there is no such version please publish result of select version()

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/wfeSEq1j BTW you appear to be using mariadb